# how to structure PHP/JavaScript trendy web application?

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications, frameworks, structure

I have a serious problem here and I need a very big help with clear answer.

*I was a Java desktop apps developer,* but now I started coding **web applications using PHP**, JavaScript, html, css, I use jQuery Ajax to send Json data and MySql as DB. But I'm building on top of an existing huge app, so my problem is that I don't really understand the structure of the app but im sure they are using their own framework!

Now I'm really excited to build a web application to myself, But The problem is that **I have no idea how to structure my app**!!! where do I start from?! and how to do it the right and trendy way, I don't mind using a frameworks but I need one that's able to modify

For PHP I don't like Codeigniter because it's like a blackbox!! if there's already made structure I can download it and understand it, that would be great. For CSS I use Boostrap it seems cool and fine for me. And for JavaScript I don't really see why JavaScript frameworks are useful! and if I can use them with a PHP framework! or does it replace it!!!

let me explain what's in my mind, I need a fixed header and footer with some body pages that loads on request (similar to Facebook) I need to use Ajax to manipulate the DOM for dynamic displaying of data, I need a pretty URL, and the basic security stuff.

thank u for reading I hope u can help I appreciate :)

Comment: And maybe we won't need so many exclamation points! not all sentences end in them!

Comment: I don't know if this question should be at SO. I think that http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate for this.

Comment: Have you googled and tried to learn how to structure webapp or had looked any php framework ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of ALL**

I would like to start my PHP devlopment in `Xampp` or `wamp` on windows and `lamp` on linux, for which i don't need to configure `PHP` and `mysql`. everything is pre-configured and ready to start.

**For Dom Manipulation and AJAX**

I definately choose the `Jquery(wrtie less, DO more)` as javascript framework. It is bundled with all stuff which a web developer require. Detailed information is available on [Jquery site](http://jquery.com/)

**General Structure of Application**

As best practise for web applications keep your server and client code separate. this [Link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/organize-your-next-php-project-the-right-way/) will give you much information for good way to start. It covers most of your question.

**Framework**

if I would realy wanted to use a framework , then `zend` framework is my ultimate choice.

As

1. Helps in Code Standerization
2. No Limit to Extend classes
3. Built in function & Classes to save lot of development

For information regarding [ZF](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/10-compelling-reasons-to-use-zend-framework/)

hope it helps